# I got a error "browser is not defined" in the console when I try create Bookmark in chrome

Tags: javascript, bookmarks

I am trying create a bookmarks (on this case in chrome)

[API/bookmarks/create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/bookmarks/create)

my code is :

```js
 function onCreated(node) {
  console.log(node);
}

var createBookmark = browser.bookmarks.create({
  title: "bookmarks.create() on MDN",
  url: "https://developer.mozilla.org/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/bookmarks/create"
});

createBookmark.then(onCreated);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>text example</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I got this error when I run the code in chrome:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: browser is not defined
```

I run other code this :

```js
function onFulfilled(bookmarkItems) {
  if (bookmarkItems.length) {
    console.log("active tab is bookmarked");
  } else {
    console.log("active tab is not bookmarked");
  }
}

function onRejected(error) {
  console.log(`An error: ${error}`);
}

function checkActiveTab(tab) {
  var searching = browser.bookmarks.search({url: tab.url});
  searching.then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
}

browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(checkActiveTab);
```

from :[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/bookmarks/search) I got the same error.

Update question :

my manifest.json in this moment:

```js
 {
    "name": "add site random",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "this is my first extension in production",
    "manifest_version": 2
  }
```

any idea because I have this error I am trying create a folder and add a site in my bookmarks from the code?

Comment: Hi Simon, If I'm not wrong. You are trying to develop a chrome extension right?

Comment: yep, I try create a chrome extension that is not my full code from my project just a part from their , but I am trying create in that part a code that it permit me createa folder in my bookmarks from chrome and add a site my extension its work is add sites when users give click in a buttom

Comment: Can you please update your post with your `manifest.json` file content?

Comment: yep give a moment i will going to edit the question

Comment: @DavidR already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your recent edit and by looking at your `manifest.json` it looks like you are missing few  `permissions` field,

Hence update your `manifest.json` like this, (then package a new extension afresh)

```
{
    "name": "add site random",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "this is my first extension in production",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["YOUR_BACKGROUND_SCRIPT_NAME.js"]
    }, 
    "permissions": [
        "notifications",
        "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Simon updated my post with **background** field. Have it updated too

Comment: it  does not working I run the code I dont got error but it does not create nothing I checked out in my bookmarks and does not  exist , my code full is here : https://gist.github.com/gilbertoquinteroA/882080787d0ecdbec95a08b3fb9d4758

Answer (score 0):

Aside from missing script calls within the `manifest` file, which after checking the commented gist link appears to have been resolved (good catch [@DavidR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51473247/2632107)!), however, both versions of the question's code are still missing a reference to the `manifest` file from within the `html`'s `<head>` block, eg. something like `<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.webmanifest">` as suggested by [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest) might just allow ya past the current issues.

For completeness sake the following is what I perpose you do to that `index.html` file...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.webmanifest">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

... and I'll also suggest renaming the `manifest` file to have the `webmanifest` extension because of [reasons](https://w3c.github.io/manifest/#media-type-registration) related to the specification.